# Can I use PyQt for both C++ and Python?

Tags: python, c++, pyqt

I'd like to learn Qt both on Python and C++. I am on Windows.

Is instaling PyQT5 with `pip3 install pyqt5` enough for C++ development or do I still have to install both Qt and PyQt?

How do I do the second option?

Comment: You will have to install both if you want to code in both Python and C++

Comment: @Asesh thank you. Would you mind answering this question instead of commenting it so I could accept your answer?

Answer (score 0):

For C++ development you're going to need a C++ compiler. On Windows Qt supports both the Mingw and Visual Studio toolchains. From there, I don't believe pyqt includes the header files you're going to need for C++ development and I cannot say for certain what toolchain it was compiled with.

Your best bet is either install the official Qt binaries for your compiler, or build the binaries from source (the later will take some time and effort.)

If you want to mix both C++ and Python in a single Qt project, check out [SIP bindings](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/intro).

Another thing to keep in mind is that pyqt5 comes with the LGPL licensed version of Qt by default. This may or may not be appropriate for your project(s), but StackOverflow isn't intended to discuss licensing issues.

Answer (score 0):

PyQt5 is for developing with Python.

If you want to code in C++ the best you do is to download Qt5 and code inside QtCreator.

Here is a link for [Qt5 Opensource](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/)